# Discrepancy between system catalog view and sp_change_users_login?

Tags: sql-server-2005, security

I want to check for orphaned users on a database. To that end, I use the following query on my SQL Server 2005 instance to get all users and their accompanying logins for a specific database (say *MyDB*):

```
SELECT  U.name AS UserName
        ,U.type_desc
        ,U.create_date
        ,U.modify_date
        ,U.default_schema_name
        ,P.name AS LoginName
        ,P.is_disabled
        ,P.type_desc
        ,P.default_database_name
        ,P.create_date
        ,P.modify_date
FROM    MyDB.sys.database_principals AS U
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.server_principals AS P ON U.sid = P.sid
WHERE   U.type IN ('G', 'S', 'U')
ORDER BY UserName;
```

When I compare the results of this query with the results of `USE MyDB; EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Report';` things do not seem to add up. The first query gives me 12 users of which 6 do not have logins; but the call to `sp_change_users_login` returns only 1 orphaned user.

Even if I take users like *guest*, *INFORMATION_SCHEMA* and *sys* out of the equation, there are still two users without a login attached in my first query that do not show up in the call to `sp_change_users_login`. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I have changed use of the deprecated `sysuser` system table to the `database_principals` system view, according to the handy MS [Mapping System Tables to System Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx) article (and Aaron of course).

Comment: Why are you using sysusers, which is deprecated? You should be using server_principals and database_principals...

Comment: Excellent catch, thanks! I adapted the query to use `database_principals` instead of `sysusers`, but unfortunately this still shows the exact same discrepancies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `sp_change_users_login` is deprecated feature and is discontinued in SQL Server 2014.

Secondly, `EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Report'` is not a proper way to get orphan users list. As with 'Report' parameter, it will execute following query. According to which it will return users where issqluser = 1 (It must be a SQl Server Login), and no result if orphan user is NT User instead of SQL User.

```
  select UserName = name, UserSID = sid,* from sysusers
            where issqluser = 1
            and   (sid is not null and sid <> 0x0)
            and   (len(sid) <= 16)
            and   suser_sname(sid) is null
            order by name
```

According to [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378(v=sql.110).aspx) *"sp_change_users_login cannot be used with a SQL Server login created from a Windows principal or with a user created by using CREATE USER WITHOUT LOGIN."*

Best script to find orphan users against all databases on an instance is already provided by "[Mark Storey-Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2374/mark-storey-smith)"

[Find orphaned users](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34976/find-orphaned-users)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I had not thought that this was due to `sp_change_users_login` - that one floats all over the internet when the talk is about orphaned users (see [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1590/understanding-and-dealing-with-orphaned-users-in-a-sql-server-database/) for example).